# String or binary data would be truncated - Add new row (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get this error when I try to add a new row.

```
HexStringToByteArray("0x546F206A65737420707573747920706C696B0D0A");
```

> String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been
>   terminated.

```
attachement.ATF_ID = 244512;
attachement.ATF_WFDID = 160489;
attachement.ATF_ATTID = 244512;
attachement.ATF_Name = "teska14.txt";
attachement.ATF_FileType = ".txt";
attachement.ATF_Value = HexStringToByteArray("0x546F206A65737420707573747920706C696B0D0A");
attachement.ATF_FileIsOcr = 0;
attachement.ATF_CreatedBy = "test";
attachement.ATF_UpdatedBy = "test";
attachement.ATF_OrginalValueHash = HexStringToByteArray("0x4C35C01D7E10FB7F7440D39932265E7C7F09A4D17FEFB55AE9E1DDAC97AD373E");
attachement.ATF_OrginalName = "test.txt";
attachement.ATF_Version = -1;
context2.WFAttachmentFiles.AddObject(attachement);
//context.AddToWFAttachmentFiles(attachement);
//context.WFAttachmentFiles.AddObject(attachement);
context2.SaveChanges();
```

HEC Code:

```
public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(hexString))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("hexString");

    if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
        throw new Exception("Invalid hex string");

    var bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
    for (int i = 2; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: It appears you changed your question, try checking db column size limits to resolve this error.

Comment: @RaviMPatel I copy this 0x546F206A65737420707573747920706C696B0D0A from ATF_Value from database. Now I want to send this for test to database. Using sql is very simple when I want to INSERT I write ATF_Value = '0x546F206A65737420707573747920706C696B0D0A'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when you see that error message:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

It means that one of the database columns is not big enough to hold the data you are trying to save.

In your case, check the size of the columns *ATF_OrginalValueHash* and *ATF_Value* in the database and maybe increase them

Comment: I copy this 0x546F206A65737420707573747920706C696B0D0A from ATF_Value from database. Now I want to send this for test to database. Usig sql is very simple when I want to INSERT I write ATF_Value = '0x546F206A65737420707573747920706C696B0D0A'

Comment: what is the datatype of the column in SQL Server  - try setting it to VARBINARY

Comment: ATF_OrginalValueHash -> binary (32), ATF_Value -> image

Comment: just noticed that that length of the data you are trying to insert to ATF_OrginalValueHash is 44 characters - which will cause the above truncation error. Try increasing the field size in the db

Comment: Damn! I've been working on this one for an hour already. Thank god i saw your post.

Comment: Hi! I have a `varbinary(max)` field and trying to upload an `8000 bytes` of data, but still giving this error, i mean it is only 8k idk why it can't handle it.

Answer (score 4):

### Update

Basic idea is to make sure whether entity properties are translated to compatible sql columns or not.

One more solution is to use [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), if you put your code there, it'll show you SQL statement fired by entity framework and that give you you sufficient insight to figure out why your code fails.

---

Usually this error shows up when you don't initialize the `DateTime` properties of your entity and you try to save changes to SQL Server database.

All c# DateTime properties are initialized to January 1, 0001, which is a minimum value of the [type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The minimum value of the datetime data type in Sql Server is [January 1, 1753](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187819%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

That results in out of range exception. If you initialize your `DateTime` properties accordingly, you shouldn't see this error. If appropriate in your scenario, you might as well consider using `SqlDateTime.MinValue` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to initialize your properties.

Comment: I found solution for date but now I edited my post to this problem. "HexStringToByteArray"